# JavaScript null and plus (+) operatior

Tags: arrays, null, javascript

I am trying to understand the core of JavaScript. I know it doesnt have much implementation value. If you dont want to answer, just leave it. However, I will appreciate if you could help to understand the following type coercion while applying addition(+).

```
1. 
null + null // 0
2.
null + undefined; // NaN
3.
null + NaN; // NaN
4. 
1 + null; //1
5. 
true + null; //1
6. 
true + [null]; //"true"
```

I know null is an empty or missing object. I will appreciate, if you can explain steps in type coercion or unary(+) operation here. Thanks for reading the question.

Comment: Please not again. In real life no one does that, why everyone cares about it?

Comment: I can't find them right now, but there are past questions that explain all the weird things that happen with `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: This is covered in [11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) - read your heart out and follow the rules. It's a simple but tedious process to work out by hand.

Comment: Its more about understanding the language than real world implementation.

Comment: I looked into the spec and specially for the one mentioned by @user2864740 that doesnt specify behavior of null + null. thats why i was curious.

Comment: `null` converts to `0` and `0 + 0` is `0`.

Comment: @KhanSharp But it does. ToPrimitive(null) -> null is applied on both operands. Since neither values after that is a string then it proceeds with ToNumber(null) + ToNumber(null) or 0 + 0 => 0.

Comment: @zerkms it's perfectly legitimate to want to know what `null + 1` is, if incrementing a variable that started with `null` - but the others not so much

Comment: @Simon_Weaver for me it makes no sense to increment `null`. I personally respect types and don't mix types in expressions, but I'm not insisting on the other people to write reasonable code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is covered in [11.6.1 The Addition operator ( + )](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) - feel free to read it and follow the rules.

The first five cases can be explained by looking at [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3):

```
Value       ToNumber(Value)
---------   ---------------
null        0
undefined   NaN
NaN         NaN
1           1
true        1
```

And `0 + 0 == 0` (and `1 + 0 == 1`), while [`x + NaN` or `NaN + x` evaluates to NaN](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.3). Since every value above is also a primitive, [`ToPrimitive(x)`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) evaluates to x (where x is not a string) and the "string concatenation clause" was not invoked.

The final case is different in that it results from the `ToPrimitive` (which ends up calling [`Array.prototype.toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2)) on the array which results in a *string* value. Thus it ends up applying `ToString`, not `ToNumber`, and follows as such:

```
   true + [null]
=> true + ""          // after ToPrimitive([null]) => ""
=> "true" + ""        // after ToString(true) => "true"
=> "true"             // via String Concatenation
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Array.toString() implements array.join('') and for this reason, [].toString() == ''  

can you elaborate why [null].toString() === ""

Comment: Well, [from Array.prototype.toString](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2): 'Let func be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of array with argument "join"..' in other words, `arr.toString()` effectively just calls `arr.join()`.

Comment: @KhanSharp: Because `Array.prototype.join` says: *"If `element` is `undefined` or `null`, Let `next` be the empty String; otherwise, let `next` be `ToString(element)`."* https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.5

Answer (score 2):

#### Conclusions derived from analysing results

`true` coerces to 1 (and `false` to 0).

`null` coerces to 0.

`undefined` coerces to NaN.

Arrays behave as:

- under unary + (`+[]`):

  - their first element if length is 1
  - 0 if they're empty
  - NaN if there's more than 1 element
- under binary + (`1+[]`):

  - coerces both operators to strings and joins them

All operations on NaN return NaN