# Create a function in Javascript from somewhat duplicate code

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I process large chunks of data. In my Javascript I receive this data via Ajax as an array of objects.

An example of this data is:

```
{ageatdeath: 0, death_count: 4, death_percent: 66.66666666666667}
```

For every age (ranging from 0 - ~100) I have an object. What I'm trying to do is group those together in ranges of 10 years (e.g. 0-10, 11-20) and create a Pie chart with plotly.

I'm able to do this, but I use a lot of almost duplicate code to achieve this. I'm wondering if there's a 'better' way to achieve this.

Here's my code for the function I'm using now.

```
function drawPieChartAgeAtDeath(data) {
var range0_10 = null;
var range11_20 = null;
var range21_30 = null;
var range31_40 = null;
var range41_50 = null;
var range51_60 = null;
var range61_70 = null;
var range71_80 = null;
var range81_90 = null;
var range90plus = null;
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 0 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 10) {
        range0_10 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 11 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 20) {
        range11_20 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 21 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 30) {
        range21_30 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 31 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 40) {
        range31_40 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 41 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 50) {
        range41_50 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 51 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 60) {
        range51_60 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 61 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 70) {
        range61_70 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 71 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 80) {
        range71_80 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 81 && data[i].ageatdeath <= 90) {
        range81_90 += data[i].death_percent;
    } else if (data[i].ageatdeath >= 91) {
        range90plus += data[i].death_percent;
    }
}

var pie_data = [{
    values: [range0_10,
        range11_20,
        range21_30,
        range31_40,
        range41_50,
        range51_60,
        range61_70,
        range71_80,
        range81_90,
        range90plus],
    labels: ['0-10 year',
        '11-20 year',
        '21-30 year',
        '31-40 year',
        '41-50 year',
        '51-60 year',
        '61-70 year',
        '71-80 year',
        '81-90 year',
        '> 90 year'],
    type: 'pie'
}];

var layout = {
    height: 400,
    width: 500
};

Plotly.newPlot('pieChartDiv', pie_data, layout);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: That won't even work to start with, using `+=` on a variable that's `null` won't give you any result you can work with.

Comment: you can use `reduce` (Array function) to obtain the object for your graph

Comment: Well, that's weird, since I am able to create a piechart with retrieving the data like this. Might I ask you to explain why += on a variable that's null won't give me any results?

Comment: Actually it works. Everything is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799408/javascript-null-and-plus-operatior). But it does not mean that is correct. In any strict type language, this would fail as null (or nil) is usually value that mean empty reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing the age by 10, and flooring it will group things into the buckets you desire.  You'll need to offset by 1 as groupings go from 0-10, then 11-20, (as opposed to 0-9, 10-19).  Below will automatically generate new buckets greater than 10 if ages exceed 100.  Buckets may be empty if there is no data for the age range.

```
function drawPieChartAgeAtDeath(data) {

    var values = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        let valueBucket = Math.floor(Math.max(data[i].ageatdeath-1,0)/10);

        values[valueBucket] = values[valueBucket] || 0;
        values[valueBucket] += data[i].death_percent;
    }

    var pie_data = [{
        values: values,
        labels: ['0-10 year',
            '11-20 year',
            '21-30 year',
            '31-40 year',
            '41-50 year',
            '51-60 year',
            '61-70 year',
            '71-80 year',
            '81-90 year',
            '> 90 year'],
        type: 'pie'
    }];

    var layout = {
        height: 400,
        width: 500
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('pieChartDiv', pie_data, layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the ranges much more elegantly like this:

```
const ranges = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => 0);
data.forEach(item => {
  const initRangeIndex = Math.floor((item.ageatdeath - 1) / 10);
  const rangeIndex = initRangeIndex === -1 ? 0 :
                       initRangeIndex > 9 ? 9
                       : initRangeIndex;
  ranges[rangeIndex] += item.death_percent;
});
const pieData = [{
  values: ranges,
  // ...
```