# Reset variable inside loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Apologies for how fundamental this question is but I can't find a definitive answer.

I have some code where I was relying on a re-declaration to reset a variable but it seems it doesn't work like I expected. Boiled down I have

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
  var j;
  j += i
}
```

Clearly pointless code but i though `j` would be reset on each loop but its just skipped. Is there another way to do this or do I just need to assign it as `null`?

Cheers

Comment: `undefined + i` results in `NaN`. If you use `var j = 0;` it works as expected. Please provide code that reproduces the issue you're asking about.

Comment: `var` is functionally scoped, IOW: it's declaration gets pushed to the top of the function,.. If you used `let` or `const` , these are block scoped, IOW: they get scoped to the beginning of a `{`

Comment: cheers both. went the `null` root as i need it be a `var`, plus `let` is not supported in GAS

Answer (score 1):

There are more than on problems with your code.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
  var j;
  j += i
}
```

1. `j` is a local variable to the `for` loop, so you won't be able to use its value outside of the loop,
2. `j` is not initialised so `NaN += i` will result to `NaN`

Change your code to something like this:

```
var j = 0; // declare the variable outside of the loop and give it an initial value
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
  j += i;
}
// use j's value somewhere else
var x = j;
```

Comment: thanks. Was just trying to illustrate the issue but yes the code is garbage! Have ended up just setting it to `null` on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Chris G, your example doesn't actually apply because the value will always be `NaN`. Declaring a variable without assigning a value will always make it `undefined`.

```
function test() {
  var j;
  Logger.log(j); // undefined
}
```

If you assign a value, even if that value is `null`, then you'll be fine. (JS will interpret `null` as zero... you can read a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799485/1329498).)

```
function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var j = null;
    j = j + i; // Explicitly writing to j
    Logger.log(j); // 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
    Logger.log(j += i); // 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
  }
}
```

As indicated by Keith, you could use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), too. That would declare a constant value, so it doesn't require resetting, but you also wouldn't be able to manipulate it.

```
function test() {
  const j = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    j = j + i; // Explicitly writing to j
    Logger.log(j); // null, null, null, null, null
    Logger.log(j += i); // 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't use `let` in Google Apps Script.